# asp.net mvc kendo ui scheduler date format

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Recently I started developing a project using kendo ui scheduler. Does anyone know how to change the date format of the start and end time? The format the scheduler is currently using is MM/dd/yyyy but I want to change it to dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Provide more info on what you have tried already

Comment: sorry, i got no idea where to change the format.

Answer (score 0):

Check the API documentation. Under fields there is a selectedDateFormat

See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#configuration-views.selectedDateFormat

If you search for format you see that there are multiple places where you can change formatting.

Comment: Hi, i added the selecteddateformat at view section still not working, the date i selected stil in format MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Did you check the other format options in the api documentation?

Comment: hi, i found that the selecteddateformat is not the setting to change the datepicker format of pop up form, my problem is the pop up datepicker not in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Better change the whole culture, because changing just the format will create future problems, when sending values to the server where the format is different.

How to keep all the cultures and formats in sync on both sides (client and server) is described [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/globalization#use-the-same-culture-on-the-server-and-client-side).